# Determine what's being displayed at the top line of a TextView within a ScrollView?

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

I currently have a `TextView` within a `ScrollView`. The `TextView` has sufficient text so that I would have to scroll up and down to see everything.

My question is: Is it possible, with Android, to be able to determine what the user currently sees as the top line of the `TextView` as they're scrolling? That is, as the user scrolls up, are we able to tell what they're currently looking at?

Comment: Do you mean the top column of the resulting list available for the user to see after scrolling?

Comment: it is possible if you somehow deal with vertical co-ordinates and keep track of where you have set the text.

Answer (score 0):

A TextView handles its own scrolling. You don't need to put a TextView inside of a ScrollView.

Comment: By default TextView not allow Scrolling you have to enable scroll using this method : setMovementMethod(new LinkMovementMethod()).

Comment: Also, this is two sentences. This is a comment at best.

Comment: @MeetTitan Until SO allows me to comment, I'll try to help this way.

Comment: @HareshChhelana Good catch/clarification. I parroted Android's docs in my answer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: @airowe, I had not considered your reputation when commenting.